# How is abiogenesis not a violation of the second law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, biology

Randomly traveling molecules plus random changes in temperature, pressure, acidity, electric charges equals a cell. That is a decrease in entropy.

How does that not violate second law of thermodynamics?

Certainly if I were to say0that particles randomly formed the letters to the first thousand characters of Romeo and Juliet over a period of a billion years, that's a huge decrease in entropy and could never happen because of the second law. And a cell is more complex than static arrangement of particles to form characters.

Comment: "Randomly traveling molecules plus random changes in temperature, pressure, acidity, electric charges equals a cell." This is absurdly wrong, the understanding has been for a long time now that the way to the first cell was probably long and arduous, and full of survival of the fittest, the first cell did not randomly spring into existence.

Comment: @Kuhlambo is it possible for randomly traveling molecules to produce first 1,000 letters to Romeo and Juliet over a billion years? If not, how can a more complex structure be created?

Comment: If anything, abiogenesis was likely [_driven_](https://youtu.be/U6QYDdgP9eg?t=227) by thermodynamics.

Comment: I wonder, why does human conciousness changes the probability of a given configuration of letters? Why is Shakespeare more peculiar that a random shuffling of characters? Shakespeare is special only to those who can find meaning in that sequence of letters... Thus your way of looking at it is biased.

Answer (score 3):

The second law applies to *closed systems*. The system you described is *not closed*; as you said yourself- you have to add energy to it from outside the system via a variation in the temperature of the system. That energy is used to perform work on it, and that work goes into changing the entropy content of the system.

Procuring and delivering that outside energy requires work, which raises the entropy content of the rest of the universe by an amount which exceeds any possible entropy reduction inside the system.

Comment: If you apply a random amount of energy randomly to a bunch of air hockey pucks, will they ever spell out the first 1,000 letters to Romeo and Juliet?

Comment: That is assuredly not a valid model of how evolution works. Who taught you that? And what are you intending to accomplish by reciting it here?

Answer (score 2):

So there are a bunch of different answers to this sort of thing. Maybe the simplest is to just take a more stark example.

One would be, “randomly traveling molecules plus random changes in temperature, pressure, acidity, electric charges,” equals a crystal. Surely whatever entropy you associate with a living cell, a crystal with its precise periodic patterns has less.

Now if we as physicists say that crystalization is impossible, then we are scientifically falsified. Crystalization happens all the time. We use it to grow these super big ultra pure silicon crystals that we dice into wafers and etch with ultraviolet light into the processor in your computer. And yeah, we just provide a really pristine environment and let random crystal growth do its thing from a little seed crystal that we put in there. Works fine!

What's really at stake is that you likely have a very limited understanding, perhaps pop science influenced, of the second law of thermodynamics. We as physicists, don't. Let me give you an example, you give this illustration of Romeo and Juliet, and you are asking the second law of thermodynamics to make a statement. But the second law is so coarse that if it were to make a statement about this particular case, then it would be the case that no bookstore could possibly have any books in it, the entropy reduction of moving all of that ink into those particular patterns is just unfathomable, such entropy reductions are impossible, therefore books must be impossible. And your physical theory is violated by the existence of books, there are lots of books, lots of circumstances where ink is indeed arranged into these interesting configurations which tell stories... The second law of thermodynamics does not prohibit books from existing, and if it did we would all fail science forever. So you're going to say something about, “I’m not interested in the ink on the page but only some abstract pattern,” and the point is that the second law of thermodynamics is much more coarse than what you are giving it credit for. The second law of thermodynamics says something about what you did, not how you did it. It makes a statement about the ink on the page, not about the abstract pattern of words in the narrative.

So for example, a physicist does not believe that entropy cannot ever go down. Because we know cases where it does. Refrigerators exist! That is heat flow from a cold place to a hot place, clearly an entropy reduction! But, we believe that a refrigerator cannot exist without external energy input: more energy goes into the hot place than came out of the cold place. And it turns out that this puts certain efficiency boundaries on what sorts of refrigerator can exist, because we can calculate perfectly reversible refrigerators that can be reversed into heat engines, and find their efficiency, and if you claim to have a more effective refrigerator, I can connect it in parallel with the reversible one to form a refrigerator that works without external energy input. Stuff like that. The arguments still exist but they become much more nuanced, and I would encourage you to embrace that nuance when you are trying to understand what the second law of thermodynamics actually says.

Comment: you avoid talking  about the law holding for closed systems.

Comment: Books and refrigerators are designed by people. Randomness did not create a book nor a refrigerator.

Comment: @Bob This is precisely my point; the second law of thermodynamics is not confined to statements about what randomness can do, it is a law of physics, it applies to everything. In fact, randomness is one of the only things that *can* violate the second law. Understanding “design by people” is a delicate and nuanced problem akin to, say, in curling, the sweepers trying to carefully adjust the path the rock goes down to get it on-target. The second law in this analogy is like showing up with a loaded cannon, “I heard you needed something round to hit a target!!”—no get out of here with that!

Answer (score 1):

You are arising many different points, and it is not easy to give a comprehensive answer. I'll limit my answer to stress a few key points you may have underestimated. They could convey to you a hint about how complex are the underlying issues.

1. It is not clear which entropy you are referring to. Thermodynamic entropy is a property of equilibrium systems, and a living cell is not in equilibrium.
2. Maximum entropy principle applies only to isolated systems. A living cell is not an isolated system.
3. Most of the processes that can be modeled with random processes in Physics are not controlled by a uniform probability distribution. Interactions do play an important role and heavily modify probability distributions.
4. Thermodynamic entropy can't be assigned to individual microscopic configurations.
5. It is impossible and meaningless to try to estimate entropy from the degree of spatial order in the system. Indeed, a fluid of hard spheres at a packing fraction of 0.60 crystallizes into a face-centered cubic crystal because the entropy of the crystal is *higher* than the entropy of the same system constrained to remain in the fluid phase.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially compare:

1. A volume of a suitable nutrient solution.
2. A volume of solution containing a cell built from the above and waste products, etc.

Both volumes have the same size for all practical purposes and contain the same atoms.
Your claim is that Volume 2 has a lower entropy.

To explore your claim, let’s first look at regular cell growth to have a more practically accessible analogy:
We start with an isolated container of nutrient solution at a suitable temperature containing a single unicellular organism (our cell).
If we wait some time, our cell has multiplied and we end up with billions of cells.
This is a standard experiment that can easily be done with bacteria (though usually the container is not isolated).
Here, we have a billion cases of converting Volume 1 into Volume 2.
If your claim is true, the total entropy of our container should have been reduced and the second law would be violated without abiogenesis coming into play.
Or with other words: **From an entropy perspective, abiogenesis is as problematic as regular cell duplication.**

However, your claim is ignoring that the temperature of our container would increase during cell growth.
The entire cell replication process is fuelled by burning sugars and other energy sources, which would lead to an increase of temperature and thus entropy – contradicting your claim.
(Also, if we could violate the second law of thermodynamics in such a simple setup, we would already have exploited this.)

Note that if we keep the temperature the same, Volume 2 is actually less entropic than Volume 1, because it is divided into two parts with different contents (which is very akin to a textbook illustration of entropy), it has some solid components, etc. However, the difference in entropy is actually quite small: The vast majority of the volume is still a watery solution of molecules with many degrees of freedom. For example, this is almost nothing compared to the entropy change when freezing the entire solution.

Comment: An existing cell has the capability of replicating.

Comment: @Bob: Yes. And thus …? (I honestly have no idea what the purpose of your comment is.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to interpret the word 'abiogenesis' in your question.

Let's first consider the example of a plant's cell converting carbon dioxide, water, dissolved nitrates and a few other trace minerals (all non-living) into living plant material. This reduces entropy, and can only happen if an even greater increase in entropy happens elsewhere. In the case of a plant, this is from sunlight - specifically, the contrast between sunlight and the darkness of outer space. Concentrated energy from photons of visible light is absorbed, and then released into the plant's environment in a more diffuse form as infrared photons and heat, and ultimately released to space. The massive increase in entropy from sunlight spreading into the dark powers the relatively tiny decrease from ordering the atoms of carbon dioxide and water into a plant. Overall, entropy increases, so the second law is obeyed.

Animals eat plants, breaking down their structure and releasing the concentrated energy as heat, which provides the massive increase in entropy that powers the smaller reduction in entropy involved in keeping them alive. Again, overall entropy increases, so the second law is obeyed.

The other interpretation of 'abiogenesis' concerns the origin of life and evolution of more complex organisms. The first self-replicating organism would certainly have been very much simpler than the simplest of organisms that exist today - more like the first ten or twenty characters of Romeo and Juliet rather than the entire play - something only a little more complex than crystalisation. As with crystalisation, some sort of thermal or chemical gradient would supply the increase in entropy to drive the smaller decrease.

Subsequently, evolution would drive the increase in complexity, through the process of *selective death*. Imagine we have a field in which there are three tethered goats, and a mass of bushes that have grown in a strange low-entropy pattern leaving perfect circles around each of the goats totally empty. It seems as if the bushes grew in precisely the shape needed to avoid being eaten by the goats. By what intelligent foresight did the bush know to do this?

It takes a moment's insight to realise that the bush didn't know - what happened was that the goats ate everything in reach, and carved perfect circular holes in the randomly spreading bush. The goats mark out spheres of death, and the bush simply fills the space between them. It always ends up in the perfect shape to evade getting eaten, no matter the complexity of the goat-free safe space it has to explore.

Where does the reduction in entropy inherent in the plant's complex shape come from? It comes from the pattern of hazards in the environment. The hazards impose a strongly non-uniform level of danger, which has a much lower entropy than a uniform one. Some behaviours are more dangerous than others. Life spreads to fill the safe areas between those dangers. And with genetic inheritance, lessons carved out on past generations by hazards can accumulate.

In thermodynamic terms, the complexity of life is no harder to explain than the way water perfectly fills the intricate spaces between the millions of pebbles on a river bed.